# Get Token Class form markdown-it on Browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, markdown-it

How do I get the Token class form markdown-it on browser?

I'm using `window.markdownit()` to get the `Markdown` class. I made a small plugin for my website that requires to genrate a token before a certain token, and I used the `Token` constructor to genrate another token, but I don't know how to access the `Token` class or constructor from the broswer so that I can use it.

I am already loading the markdown-it libary using a `script` tag in the HTML code.

I tried to access it from `window.markdownit` but it wasn't there and when I `console.log(window.markdownit)`, it would return a function. I tried `window.Token` but it is not there.